# Change of coordinates introduced through dx

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, supersymmetry

Hi,

I have a superspace spanned by 4 commuting coordinates + 2 anti-commuting ones $\{x^\mu,\theta^\alpha\}$, I have to do the change of coordinates $dx^\mu\to dy^\mu= dx^\mu+d\theta^\alpha \eta_\alpha^{\;\:\mu}$ where $\eta$ have to be a local function i.e: $\eta\equiv\eta(x)$, and leave the $d\theta$'s unchanged, so how can I translate this change on coordinates themselves? In particular I need to express $\partial_\mu$ in the new coordinate system.

If the $\eta$ fcts where global it would be simply $x^\mu\to y^\mu= x^\mu+\theta^\alpha \eta_\alpha^{\;\:\mu}$, so what if $\eta$'s where not global?

Comment: Please do not use words like "local" and "global" in this context.  By a "global function"  you mean a *constant* and by a "local function"  you simply mean a *function*.  This sort of nonstandard language might be confusing to some people.


Comment: Sorry, bad physicist language I know ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I would not call $dx^\mu \mapsto dy^\mu$ a change of coordinates.  Not every transformation on 1-forms is going to be the pullback by a smooth map.  In fact, your question is whether the transformation $(dx^\mu,d\theta^\alpha) \mapsto (dy^\mu,d\theta^\alpha)$ comes from a change of coordinates.

Pullbacks commute with exterior derivative, so that if $dy^\mu$ is a pullback then applying $d$ to your $dy^\mu$ should give zero.  If you do that you find that it is not unless $\eta$ is constant.

Comment: Thank you for this very clear answer... nevertheless I wonder how I can now express my partial derivatives!

Comment: The partial derivatives are canonically dual to the differentials, so they transform as the "inverse transpose".  Be careful that just because you have declared that $d\theta^\alpha$ does not transform, this does not mean that the partial derivative $\partial/\partial\theta^\alpha$ does not either!

Answer (score 1):

Ok here are the partial derivatives $k_M$:

they are dual to $\{b^M\} = \{dy^\mu,d\theta^\alpha\}$ ie:

$b^M(k_N)=\delta_N^M$

Writing $k_N=(k_N)^{\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}+(k_N)^{\alpha}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^\alpha}$ and solving $b^\nu(k_\mu)=\delta^\nu_\mu,\;b^\mu(k_\alpha)=0; \; b^\alpha(k_\nu)=0;\;b^\alpha(k_\beta)=\delta^\alpha_\beta$ one finds:

$(k_\mu)^\nu=\delta^\nu_\mu,\;(k_\mu)^\alpha=0;\;(k_\alpha)^\beta=\delta^\beta_\alpha;\;(k_\alpha)^\nu=-\eta_\alpha^{\;\;\mu}$

So:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial y^\mu} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial y^\alpha} = -\eta^{\;\;\mu}_\alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^\alpha}$

Comment: There is some problem with the notation in the left-hand side of the last equation.  You'd like to say that this is $\partial/\partial\theta^\alpha$, but then then equation would be inconsistent.  Anyway, it's clear what you mean.